# Adding additional display data to Sql Server Database Diagrams

Tags: sql-server, database-diagram

I could not find on the internet resources that show how can I make a Sql Server Database Diagram show each table's unique indexes.

**I know I can**:

- Add relationship labels - **not what I want**.
- Play with the options in right-clicking a table in the diagram ->
  table view - **not what I want** (custom / Modify custom does not
  help me    either,  I want none of those options).

Is it possible ?